# I'm new to flask api programming

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, dictionary

I'm having a problem with my code, no errors occur but for some reason I'm not getting the desired
outcome

This is the 'json' data that the user will receive

```
books = [
  {'id': 0,
   'title': 'A fire Upon the Deep',
   'author': 'Vernor Vinge',
   'first_sentence': 'The coldsleep itself was dreamless.',
   'year_published': '1992'},
  {'id': 1,
   'title': 'The Ones Who Walk Away From Omelas',
   'author': 'Ursula K. Le Guin',
   'first_sentence': 'With a clamor of bells that set the swallows soaring, the \
    Festival of Summer came to the city Omelas, bright-towered by the sea.',
   'published': '1973'},
  {'id': 2,
   'title': 'Dhalgren',
   'author': 'Samuel R. Delany',
   'first_sentence': 'to wound the autumnal city.',
   'published': '1975'}
 ]
```

If no id's exist then it returns an error message which it's not supposed to seeing as each book has an id

```
@app.route('/api/v1/resource/books', methods=['GET'])
def api_id():
    if 'id' in request.args:
        id = int(request.args['id'])
    else:
        return "Error: ID not provided. Please specify an ID"

    results = []

    for book in books:
        if book['id'] == id:
            results.append(book)

return jsonify(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the request url will be something like http://localhost:5000/api/v1/resource/books/?id=1

For multiple book ids, it will be something like  http://localhost:5000/api/v1/resource/books/?id=1&id=2

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

books = [
  {'id': 0,
   'title': 'A fire Upon the Deep',
   'author': 'Vernor Vinge',
   'first_sentence': 'The coldsleep itself was dreamless.',
   'year_published': '1992'},
  {'id': 1,
   'title': 'The Ones Who Walk Away From Omelas',
   'author': 'Ursula K. Le Guin',
   'first_sentence': 'With a clamor of bells that set the swallows soaring, the \
    Festival of Summer came to the city Omelas, bright-towered by the sea.',
   'published': '1973'},
  {'id': 2,
   'title': 'Dhalgren',
   'author': 'Samuel R. Delany',
   'first_sentence': 'to wound the autumnal city.',
   'published': '1975'}
 ]
   
@app.route("/api/v1/resource/books/", methods=["GET"])
def api_id():

    # This will look for 'id' in the url. If there's no id/ids, it will take None as default value
    bids = request.args.getlist('id')
    # if you are expecting to serve only one id at a time, use >> request.args.get('id')

    if bids:
        results = []
        for book in books:
            for bid in bids: # this for loop won't be required for strictly single id
                if book['id'] == int(bid):
                    results.append(book)
        return jsonify(results)
    else:
        return "Error: ID not provided. Please specify an ID"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This code is working for me. I hope it does for you as well.

Request Url:

> http://localhost:5000/api/v1/resource/books/?id=0&id=2

Output:

```
[{"author":"Vernor Vinge","first_sentence":"The coldsleep itself was dreamless.","id":0,"title":"A fire Upon the Deep","year_published":"1992"},{"author":"Samuel R. Delany","first_sentence":"to wound the autumnal city.","id":2,"published":"1975","title":"Dhalgren"}]
```

Request Url:

> http://localhost:5000/api/v1/resource/books/?id=0

Output:

```
[{"author":"Vernor Vinge","first_sentence":"The coldsleep itself was dreamless.","id":0,"title":"A fire Upon the Deep","year_published":"1992"}]
```

Request Url:

> http://localhost:5000/api/v1/resource/books/

Output:

```
Error: ID not provided. Please specify an ID
```